# how to get access to log files created by WP7 profiler

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows phone performance analysis creates a file with .sap extension. This .sap file is a xml file that contains information about what has been probed i.e. memory, code, visual. It also contains link to the log file :
File Type="NativeFormat" Path="PerformanceLogs\SampleApp634619173996182143\tmp9EE1.tmp"

I'm not able to open tmp9EE1.tmp as I fail to find what Type="NativeFormat" means.
Basically what I want from profiler tool is:
- an xml or csv or any file that contains memory consumption information for particular time period
eg. 100 ms = 10 mb, 200 ms = 12 mb, 300 ms = 13 mb etc.

Instead of the graphical tool (as provided by profiler), I want result in any readable format text,csv,xml.

Please let me know if it is possible.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to solve it with a performance analysis tool, but you could do this with a timer and then log it yourself. I used this code to see how much memory my app is using, and you could tweak it to fit your needs.

And one more thing i added this to App-s constructor.

I hope this will help you.

```
    var timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        var mempeakuse = (long)Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage");
        var memuse = (long)Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage");
        var maxmem = (long)Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceTotalMemory");
        memuse /= 1024 * 1024;
        mempeakuse /= 1024 * 1024;
        maxmem /= 1024 * 1024;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Mem usage: {0} / {1} / {2} MB", memuse, mempeakuse, maxmem));
    };
    timer.Start();
```

Comment: wrapping this with #DEBUG tags would make this even better :)

Comment: @willmel yes that is true, would look better but that's not so hard to do. :)